# Curl of unit normal vector on a surface is zero?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

I have a scalar field $\phi$. From this field, I define an iso-surface $\phi=\phi_{iso}$.

The unit normal vector on this surface is

$\vec{n}=\left(\frac{\nabla\phi}{|\nabla\phi|}\right)_{\phi_{iso}}$

I have a book, where the author says: For any surface unit normal vector the following is true:

$\nabla\times\vec{n}=0$

I found some other sources saying the same:

[rot(n)=0](https://books.google.de/books?id=eec8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22rot(n)%22+%22normal+vector%22&source=bl&ots=1qBZf_CpBj&sig=nya-qX0zmm9azYZ0-AkZe6-zWYg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigqIzBldrJAhXLSRoKHVOsA6wQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22rot(n)%22%20%22normal%20vector%22&f=false) ("since rot(n)=0")

[curl(n)=0](http://www.pp.bme.hu/ee/article/viewFile/4463/3568) on page 4 between eq. 20 and 21

Is this true for any surface? Because if I try to prove this myself, I get stuck really quick:

$\nabla\times\vec{n}=\nabla\times\left(\frac{\nabla\phi}{|\nabla\phi|}\right)=
\nabla\left(\frac{1}{|\nabla\phi|}\right)\times\nabla\phi+\frac{1}{|\nabla\phi|}\underbrace{\nabla\times\nabla\phi}_{=0}=\frac{1}{|\nabla\phi|^2}\nabla(|\nabla\phi|)\times\nabla\phi$

I can't see why this is supposed to be zero, since $|\nabla\phi|\ne\text{const}$ generally. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hint: if $\vec {n}$ is a vector field, try to show that it is conservative. Then the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @SalmonKiller. But in my case, the scalar field $\phi$ is the temperature field from a 3D simulation. It doesn't have any special properties, it is just an arbitrary scalar field. Every test for a vector field being conservative I do fails because $|\nabla\phi|$ is not constant. Can you be a bit more specific? Maybe I'm just missing an obvious point :D

Comment: Think about applying Stokes‘s Theorem to tiny closed curves on your level surface.

Comment: @g3lol another point to consider: the vector field must be "continuous" for most of these theorems to apply.

Comment: Please note $\nabla\left(\frac{1}{|\nabla\phi|}\right)$ will have a negative sign in the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how you define the vector field $\vec{n}$ AWAY from the surface $\phi = \phi_{iso}$. On the surface $\vec{n}$ is well-defined (up to choice of orientation).

1. Choice one: define $\vec{n}$, as you did, to be globally the normalized gradient of $\phi$. That is, set $\vec{n} = \frac{\nabla \phi}{|\nabla\phi|}$. In this case $\nabla\times \vec{n} = 0$, when evaluated at the surface $\{\phi = \phi_{iso}\}$, if and only if $|\nabla \phi|$ is constant along the surface.
2. Choice two: forget more or less about the function $\phi$. Define the function
   $$ \psi = \frac{1}{|\nabla \phi|} (\phi - \phi_{iso}) $$
   Observe that the surface you are interested in is the surface $\{ \psi = 0\}$. Computing the gradient $\nabla \psi$ you have that 
   $$ \nabla \psi = \frac{\nabla\phi}{|\nabla \phi|} - \frac{(\phi-\phi_{iso}) \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla^2\phi}{|\nabla\phi|^3} $$
   The key is that the second term vanishes on the surface, since there $\phi = \phi_{iso}$. So $\nabla\psi$ restricted to the surface is *still* the unit normal vector field. But $\nabla \times (\nabla \psi)$ is clearly zero. (Note, however, $\nabla\psi$ is not guaranteed to be a unit vector field away from the surface.)

---

More generally: given a compact smooth surface $\Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, there exists a radius $r > 0$ such that on the set $S = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^3: \mathrm{dist}(x,\Sigma) < r\}$ we can solve the [eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation#Mathematical_description) $|\nabla \Psi| = 1$ to get a function $\Psi:S \to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\Sigma = \Psi^{-1}(0)$ and $\nabla \Psi$ is the unit normal vector field for any level set $\Psi^{-1}(c)$. Then in this formulation we see that the unit normal vector field $\vec{n} = \nabla \Psi$ is curl-free everywhere in $S$. The number $r$, which is generically finite, is related to the radius of curvature of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Would you please make it clearer? For instance, it seems $\nabla\phi\cdot \nabla^2\phi$ (in your conclusion equation) doesn't make sense with $\cdot$ the Laplace which is a scalar.

Comment: @MathArt: $\nabla^2\phi$ is the Hessian, not the Laplacian. It is symmetric so you can dot it in either the left or the right.

Comment: Reading this answer and the original question again 5 years later: I wonder if the question is about whether the _normal projection_ of $\nabla\times \vec{n}$ is zero; in which case the answer is "always". (This is the part that is independent of the extension off of the iso surface.)

Comment: That is where I misunderstood. Thanks.