# Curl of normal unit vector of a smooth and closed surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, curl

Let's say we have a curvilinear coordinate system $(\rho,\theta,\zeta)$. Also, let's say we have a smooth and closed surface $\Gamma$ parameterized as $\Gamma: \mathbf{S}(\rho(\theta,\zeta),\theta,\zeta) = \mathbf{S}(\theta,\zeta)$. Let $\mathbf{n}$ be the unit vector normal to the surface $\Gamma$.

Is $\nabla \times \mathbf{n} = 0 $ guaranteed for any $\Gamma$ that is closed and smooth?

I know there's a similar question about this here: [Curl of unit normal vector on a surface is zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574529/curl-of-unit-normal-vector-on-a-surface-is-zero)

However, I do not know if you can write $\mathbf{n}$ as $\frac{\nabla \phi}{|\nabla \phi|}$ for any smooth and closed surface.

Comment: $\mathbf n$ is defined only on $\Gamma$, so how do you define its curl?

Comment: @TedShifrin You can always define the normal vector so that it is continuous in space and literally coincides with the normal unit vector on the surface $\Gamma$, as shown in the other post I attached to this one.